# How to add spaces into the address filled in firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String userName = name.getText().toString();
    String userAddress = address.getText().toString();
    String userCity = city.getText().toString();
    String userCode = postalCode.getText().toString();
    String userNumber = phoneNumber.getText().toString();

    String final_address = "";

    if (!userName.isEmpty()){
        final_address+= userName;
    }
    if (!userCity.isEmpty()){
        final_address+= userCity;
    }
    if (!userAddress.isEmpty()){
        final_address+= userAddress;
    }
    if (!userCode.isEmpty()){
        final_address+= userCode;
    }
    if (!userNumber.isEmpty()){
        final_address+= userNumber;
    }
    if (!userName.isEmpty() && !userAddress.isEmpty() && !userCity.isEmpty() && !userCode.isEmpty() && !userNumber.isEmpty()){

        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("userAddress",final_address);

        firestore.collection("CurrentUser").document(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .collection("Address").add(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(AddAddressActivity.this, "Address Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }else {
        Toast.makeText(AddAddressActivity.this, "Kindly Fill All Fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

i used these codes to get the input.

the data collected in the firestore looks like this:
abxcityxyz12341334567890

all this data gets mixed up

how can i add spaces in between  the codes so that the collected information is understandable.

this is what i get as data stored in firestore

[image]

this is my input in the application

[image]

Comment: "the data collected in the firestore looks like this: abxcityxyz12341334567890" I'm not sure I understand what you mean by this. Can you show a screenshot of both the input, and how it shows up in that unwanted format?

Comment: sure sir the required screenshots have been added in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply concat an empty space wherever you need it.

`final_address += userCity;` becomes `final_address += ' ' + userCity;`

The above adds a space infront of userCity.

So do that for the userAddress, userCode and userNumber.

Comment: Glad I could help.